# Total Correctness

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, while-loop

[X = M & m >= 0]

```
y := 0;
z := 0;

while y <> x do
z := z + x;
y:= y +1
end
```

[z = m x m]

Could you help me to solve total correctness of this algorithm?

Comment: what do you mean by total correctness?

Comment: like this: https://courses.cs.ttu.ee/w/images/9/91/While_program_example_2015.pdf

Comment: Are you asking whether the algorithm is correct? If so, yes it is. `y` increases to `m` in steps of `1`, `z` increases to `m*m` in steps of `m`.

Comment: Could you give me the notation?

Comment: I mean, could you solve me like in the link I've given?

Comment: Googling around a little, it looks like "total correctness" means "given the precondition (the thing in the first set of square brackets) and the source code, prove that the source code eventually terminates, and when it does, that the postcondition (the thing in the second set of square brackets) always holds."

Comment: @yusuf, "could you solve [the problem for] me?" Sorry, that question is a little too broad for SO. Do you have any questions more specific than "how do I do this?"?

Comment: Is the formalism given in the link the [Hoare calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic)?

Comment: yes it is given there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove **total correctness** of a program we need to prove both **partial correctness** and **termination** of the program.

### Partial Correctness

```
|- assert(P); C; assert(Q);
```

Proving partial correctness means that for all execution of C that start in a state satisfying the precondition P, then the postcondition Q is satisfied at termination (if it terminates).

For your specific program, we are proving partial correctness for a while loop, which will have a proof structure:

```
    assert(P);
    assert(Inv);
while B do {
        assert(Inv ^ B);
    C;
        assert(Inv);
};
    assert(Inv ^ !B);
    assert(Q);
```

Where `Inv` is the **loop invariant**(an assertion that is true before and after each execution of a loop) and `B` is the guard of the loop.

### Termination

To show that a while-loop terminates we need to find the **bounding function**. The bounding function or variant is an integer expression that:

- Involve the variables of the loop condition
- Must always be non-negative
- Decreases with each iteration of the loop

If the bounding function decreases with each iteration and is always non-negative, then it will eventually reach 0, meaning the loop terminates.

**Please give this a try. I will post my solution at a later time.**

EDIT: SOLUTION

This is what we get after filling out the boiler plate:

```
    assert(x==m ^ m>=0);    [Precondition]
y := 0;
z := 0;
    assert(z==y*x ^ x==m);  [Inv]
while y<>x do {
        assert(z==y*x ^ x==m ^ y<>x);    [Inv ^ Guard]
    z := z + x;
    y := y + 1;
        assert(z==y*x ^ x==m);           [Inv]
};
    assert(z==y*x ^ x==m ^ !(y<>x));     [Inv ^ !Guard]

    assert(z==m*m);    [Postcondition]
```

Now work backwards from the bottom up to fill in the missing parts:

```
    assert(x==m ^ m>=0);    [Precondition]
    assert(0==0*x ^ x==m);  [by arith]
y := 0;
    assert(0==y*x ^ x==m);  [by assignment]
z := 0;
    assert(z==y*x ^ x==m);  [Inv: by assignment]
while y<>x do {
        assert(z==y*x ^ x==m ^ y<>x);    [Inv ^ Guard]
        assert(z+x==y*x+x ^ x==m);       [by arith]
        assert(z+x==(y+1)*x ^ x==m);     [by arith]
    z := z + x;
        assert(z==(y+1)*x ^ x==m);       [by assignment]
    y := y + 1;
        assert(z==y*x ^ x==m);           [Inv: by assignment]
};
    assert(z==y*x ^ x==m ^ !(y<>x));     [Inv ^ !Guard]

    assert(z==m*m);    [Postcondition: by VC1]

VC1 (Verification Condition): z==y*x ^ x==m ^ !(y<>x) |= z==m*m
1) z==y*x ^ x==m ^ !(y<>x)    premise
2) z==y*x ^ x==m ^ y==x       by negation
3) z==y*x ^ x==m ^ y==m       by equality
4) z==m*m                     by equality
```

The bounding function is: **x - y**